# TypeError: string indices must be integers Search API Twitter

Tags: json, api, twitter, python-requests, twitter-oauth

I have been fiddling with Twitter Search API, I have coded a Code like this using `requests`

```
    import requests
    from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
    url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json"
    auth = OAuth1('redacted', 'redacted','redacted', 'redacted')
    requests.get(url, auth=auth)
    r = requests.get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40twitterapi", auth=auth)
    print r.json()
```

The output of this i Get Some JSON Blobs which contains information i wanted to access `text` part of the JSON data for that i used the following code

```
for tweet in r.json():
    print tweet['text']
```

The error message is `TypeError: string indices must be integers` . I fiddled more and used this code

```
for tweet in r.json():
    print tweet
```

That gave me output `search_metadata` & `statuses`. So how do i print only tweets which currently gives me TypeError. Help would be appreciated :(

Comment: You are taking an index of the string with `tweet['text']`. String indices take an int index, not a string

Comment: @AndrewL. I figured it out and it works in the same way tweet['text'] only, i will answer to my own question wait

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out where i was doing mistake, With some comments out there telling me that Indexes must be in integer but to Query out any specific JSON having `text` the Code context of mine was appropriate.

The solution for this is

```
for tweet in r.json()['statuses']:
      print tweet['text']
```

I don't know who downvoted, but seriously if you can't answer, than downvoting makes no sense.. if you know what i mean  .Cheers, any other simple solution would be appreciateed